# How to upload file in akka http 10 file size > 100 KB

Tags: scala, akka-stream, akka-http

I have akkka http server(version 10.0) for make request upload file from postman to another service (it connect amazon s3)

1. use image file (image size = 275 KB) and it have exception

> akka.stream.impl.SubscriptionTimeoutException: Substream Source has not been materialized in 5000 milliseconds

2. use image size < 20 KB, it work

Why ??

this is my code

```
(post &
        entity(as[Multipart.FormData])) { (formData) =>
        val fileNamesFuture = formData.parts.mapAsync(1) { p =>
          Future.successful(p.entity, p.name, p.filename)
        }.runFold(List.empty[(BodyPartEntity, String, Option[String])])(_ :+ _)

        val req = fileNamesFuture flatMap { a => createRequestUploadImage(a.find(x => x._2 == "image").get, Url, token) }
        onComplete(req flatMap {
          HttpService.response
        }) {
          case Success(data) =>
            println(data)
            complete("OK")
        }}
```

make request method

```
def createRequestUploadImage(file: (BodyPartEntity, String, Option[String]), url: String, token: Option[String] = None): Future[HttpRequest] = {
val formData =
  Multipart.FormData(
    Source.single(
      Multipart.FormData.BodyPart(
        "data",
        file._1,
        Map("filename" -> file._3.getOrElse("")))))

Marshal(formData).to[RequestEntity]
  .map(e => HttpRequest(HttpMethods.POST, uri = url, entity = e)
    .withHeaders(RawHeader("Authorization", token.getOrElse(""))))}
```

get url(after upload) from another service

```
def response(req: HttpRequest): Future[Response] = {
val connectionFlow: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Future[Http.OutgoingConnection]] =
  Http().outgoingConnection(host = req.uri.authority.host.address(), port = req.uri.effectivePort).async

for {
  res <- Source.single(req).via(connectionFlow).runWith(Sink.head)
  data <- Unmarshal(res.entity).to[String]
} yield (res, data)}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will help you

Put this in your application.conf file

100m means 100 MB

```
akka.http.server.parsing.max-content-length = 100m
```

Comment: I use toStrict() and it work for me, thank you for answer